# send multipart response in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, response, multipart

I am working on apis which is developed in spring boot. Now I have one API in which I have to send response which contains one binary file and and xml.
Both will be seperated by multipart boundary.
So is there any way to do this?

Comment: did you get any solution?

Comment: yes i got the solution

Comment: can you pls share the link

Comment: I did not get any solution if you have link or code pls share

Comment: Corrently I dnt have code But I can give you idea
You can create your own response using string and concatenate that string with boundary and then append remaining response. So the receiver will be able to separate the response using the boundary.

Comment: @Darsshan Sathwara finally I did using spring boot I am posting my code.

Answer (score 11):

In spring boot try following the way to send a response in multipart.

```
   @RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.GET },value = "/multipartdata",produces=MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> gerMultipartData()
            throws Exception {
        MultiValueMap<String, Object> formData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
        formData.add("first_name",  "ganesh");
        formData.add("last_name", "patil");
        formData.add("file-data_1", new FileSystemResource("C:\Users\ganesh\img\logo.png"));
        formData.add("file-data_2", new FileSystemResource("C:\Users\ganeshg\Desktop\download.jpg"));
        formData.add("file-data_3", new FileSystemResource("C:\Users\ganeshg\Desktop\odstext.txt"));
        formData.add("file-data_4", new FileSystemResource("D:\Agent\152845.docx"));
        formData.add("file-data_5", new FileSystemResource("D:\testxls.xlsx"));
        return new ResponseEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(formData, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Comment: FYI. If you want to customize your boudary. then you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45401043/boundary-in-contenty-type-is-overwritten-by-formhttpmessageconverter/60348928).

Comment: And if you want to stream your response. you can write the multipart body manually in outputstream. [here](https://dzone.com/articles/streaming-data-with-spring-boot-restful-web-servic) is a demo.

Comment: Does it have to be `MultiValueMap`? Can't regular Map do the job, assuming each name has only one value?

Comment: Isn't this MULTIPART_FORM_DATA related to the HTTP request and not the HTTP response? This is better suited for file upload with form data. Cant, we use StreamingResponseBody to compose multipart responses?

Comment: Would there be an advantage to using 'Part' instead of 'Object' in the MultiValueMap? That is, return ResponseEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Part>> perhaps? When receiving multipart data, Spring docs mention using 'Part', specifically [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webflux/controller/ann-methods/multipart-forms.html#:~:text=MultiValueMap%3CString%2C%20Part%3E)