# Boundary in Contenty-type is overwritten by FormHttpMessageConverter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using FormHttpMessageConverter in Spring Framework.
For sending a file by restTemplate, I added FormHttpMessageConverter in my project.

The problem is the server where takes the file asked string encrypted Content-type of me.
I had to send the file with Content-type: multipart/form-data, but they asked "Content-type: multipart/form-data;" and **"*boundary:XXXX*"**.

So I tried to make a value for boundary before send the file. However, the boundary value was overwritted when RestTemplate.exchage()
The reason was FormHttpMessageConverter. FormHttpMessageConverter caught the request for converting.
If Content-type is multipart/form-data, FormHttpMessageConverter overwrites boundary value by this code.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/5f4d1a4628513ab34098fa3f92ba03aa20fc4204/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/converter/FormHttpMessageConverter.java#L336

I couldn't find the way to avoid this problem, so I copied that code at the link, and made a file "xxxFormHttpMessageConverter" and modified the method "writeMultipart".

Do someone know how to avoid this overwriting?

Comment: In the class you link, the `generateMultipartBoundary` method is `protected`, and appears to be doing what you want.  You'll still need to extend the class, but simply overwriting this one method with your fixed `String`, e.g., `"myCustomBoundary".getBytes()` should work.

Comment: Indeed. I missed `generateMultipartBoundary()` is protected. Thank you! I will try that.

Comment: All right. I tried this way. It works. It's so helpful.
But, boundary value is generated randomly every time it called in general.
I cannot be certain that this is a right way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spring boot you can customize boundary by creating a new HttpMessageConverter bean. And Spring boot will replace the older one automaticlly. The code looks like this:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomerHttpMessageConverter {

    public static final String MY_BOUNDARY = "XXXXXXXX";

    @Bean
    public HttpMessageConverter<MultiValueMap<String, ?>> createCustomerFormHttpMessageConverter() {
        return new CustomerFormHttpMessageConverter();
    }

    static class CustomerFormHttpMessageConverter extends FormHttpMessageConverter {
        @Override
        protected byte[] generateMultipartBoundary() {
            return MY_BOUNDARY.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        }
    }
}
```

You can find more information [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-httpmessageconverter-rest).